# Link in thumbnail images in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, image

How to assign links to thumbnail images. I have portfolio with thumbnail images of different websites and i have to add link to them.

```
<div class="showcase-image">
    <?php
        $thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'large' );
        if(has_post_thumbnail()): echo '<img src="'.$thumbnail[0].'"/>'; else: ?>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: set the `href` attribute in the `img` tag to your url.

Comment: @KeVin `href` attribute on an `img` tag?

Comment: ehh, my fingers were faster than my brain. Add an `a` element around your `img` tag and set the `href` tag of the `a` element to your url.

Comment: If you're wanting to link to the post then you can use `get_permalink()` as stated in the [docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div class="showcase-image">
    <?php
        $thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'large' );
        if(has_post_thumbnail()): echo '<a href="'.$thumbnail[0].'" > <img src="'.$thumbnail[0].'"/></a>'; else: ?>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: it works but it links to the thumbnail image. I want to add different link for (http://example.com) and for next image (http://example2.com)